# Images in HTML file not being displayed on iPhone

Tags: html, iphone, image

I made some simple HTML files and tried to open them on my iPhone, in both the files app and some third party HTML viewer apps from the App Store, but the images are not being displayed, not a single one.

It‘s not because the image is in another folder or the file path is incorrect, I‘ve checked all that. Also I‘ve looked up the issue and it seems that this might be caused by too large png files, but I tried to resize the images and also changing them to jpg, but still didn‘t work. So what could be the issue here?

I‘ve attached an image of the result that I get with this example code (the png file is in the same folder as the HTML file):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    
<body>
    Test
    <br>
    <br>
    <img src="image.png">

</body>
</html>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpETI.png)

Comment: which browser did you use?

Comment: On my laptop I used Microsoft Edge, everything worked perfectly fine there. On the iPhone I used the files app and various third party HTML viewer apps.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a security related issue.

I ran into this helping a friend who was working on an email newsletter and sent it to herself as an attachment. Opening in gmail showed the same behavior - no images.

So I tried saving the file to the Files app and opening it. Same thing. Loading the page from a web server it worked n

It doesn’t entirely make sense why they need to be so strict - the same thing in a desktop browser would show images. But I don’t think there’s anything you can do in this case.

Saving as a complete web page archive may work if the goal is to email an attachment that someone needs to open - but that’s not a common thing to do and if you send the message as a real email it’ll work fine.